# Why doesn't C++11 standard provide other lock free atomic structure

Tags: c++, atomic, lock-free, stdatomic, lockless

I've known that `std::atomic_flag` is guaranteed to be lock free whereas other atomic stuffs, such as `std::atomic<int>`, `std::atomic<bool>` are not, meaning that they may be generated with lock.

My question is why there is only one thing `std::atomic_flag` is lock free and others may be not? Why don't we force to use lock free to generate things like `std::atomic<bool>`? Is there some technique reason?

Comment: The simple answer: If on a given machine a sequence of instructions is needed to perform the action on T it must be guaranteed that these action sequence is not interruptible. Typically a machine can not guarantee a sequence of instructions can not be interrupted without a lock. So only these operations on T are lock free which can be managed in a single assembly instruction. So the reason is: Hardware! :-) Some cores support things like "test bit and set" or manipulate a 4 or 8 byte int in a single instruction (read-modify-write) but a lot of cores can not do this within a single instruction!